# How to export stats from Google Play Dev Console in CSV format?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'd like to export all the CSV which is in the Google Play Developer Console, but in the Google play Developer API there are no function to do this.

Which method can i use to get all the CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Re, Resolved with request module.**